# Bijection between the inversion set of a word $w$ and $[\ell(w)]$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $w \in S_n$, where $S_n$ is the symmetric group generated by simple reflections $s_1, \ldots, s_{n-1}$. The inversion set of $w$ is defined by $\{(i,j) : i,j \in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}, i<j, w(i) > w(j) \}$.

We have that the number of inversions of $w$ is equal to the length of $w$ (denoted by $\ell(w)$).

What is the bijection between the inversion set of a word $w$ and $[\ell(w)]=\{1,2,\ldots, \ell(w)\}$? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand the question. There are $\ell(w)!$ such bijections.

Comment: There is a way of listing the inverted pairs given a shortest expression of $w$ as a product of the simple reflections. As a special case of listing the positive roots mapped into negative ones by such a reduced word in a Coxeter group. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen, thank you very much. Yes, this is what I am asking about. Maybe you can write it as an answer?